# Zelda Link's Awakening: missing key

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

In the angler's dungeon, there is one room where you need to get a key to open a door in the lower levels, but the key chest does not appear.
To make the chest appear, you have to kill all the enemies in the room, but it never appears.

[image: The screenshot of the level where I struggle]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems your picture is not from Angler's Dungeon (number 4) but the Bottle Grotto (number 2).

If I recall correctly, this room is a puzzle in which you have to kill the enemies in a certain order.

A tablet somewhere in the dungeon could help you find out the order.

**TABLET / CLUE SPOILER :**

> First, defeat the imprisoned Pols Voice,
> Last, Stalfos...

**Answer** :
The order is

> Bunny, Bat, Blue Skelteon

Comment: It seems this puzzle is mostly designed to figure out who read the manual and knows that the rabbit looking enemy is called a Pols Voice.

Comment: Interestingly, this is not an issue in French where the monsters are not defined by their names but their features (a rabbit and a specter).